# Concatenate one table to another using a key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file. `df` represents this file. I have two ids in this file. Once the `d_id` and the `i_id`. The program now runs through a certain algorithm and gives me the `probability` and the `d_id` back in an ordered row (I can also deactivate this ordered row if it should be easier).
In any case, I would like to receive the `i_id` instead of the `d_id`. Can someone help me with how I map the `d_id` to the `i_id` and only get the `i_id` as the last output shows?

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'d_id': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4],
     'i_id': [99, 98, 98, 97, 97, 97, 96]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print(df)

   d_id  i_id
0     1    99
1     2    98
2     2    98
3     3    97
4     3    97
5     3    97
6     4    96

d_new = {'d_id': [4, 2, 1, 3],
     'probability': [0.8557, 0.83215, 0.2563, 0.14521]}
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data=d_new)
   d_id  probability
0     4      0.85570
1     2      0.83215
2     1      0.25630
3     3      0.14521

print(df_new)
```

What I tried

```
result = df.merge(df_new, right_on='d_id')
print(result)

[OUT] TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

What I want

```
   i_id   probability
0     96      0.85570
1     98      0.83215
2     99      0.25630
3     97      0.14521
```

---

What I also tried

```
result = df.merge(df_new, how='left', on='d_id')
print(result)

   d_id  i_id  probability
0     1    99      0.25630
1     2    98      0.83215
2     2    98      0.83215
3     3    97      0.14521
4     3    97      0.14521
5     3    97      0.14521
6     4    96      0.85570
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to process your resulted data.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'d_id': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4],
     'i_id': [99, 98, 98, 97, 97, 97, 96]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

d_new = {'d_id': [4, 2, 1, 3],
     'probability': [0.8557, 0.83215, 0.2563, 0.14521]}
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data=d_new)

result = df.merge(df_new, how='left', on='d_id')[['i_id', 'probability']]
result.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

result:

```
   i_id  probability
0    99      0.25630
1    98      0.83215
3    97      0.14521
6    96      0.85570
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
result = df.drop_duplicates('d_id').merge(df_new, how='right', on='d_id')
```

Output:

```
   d_id  i_id  probability
0     4    96      0.85570
1     2    98      0.83215
2     1    99      0.25630
3     3    97      0.14521
```

Comment: Thanks! But how could I only get the i_id and the probability?

Comment: Chain the above with `[['i_id','probability']]`?